# Ограничения на похожие товары Magento

Tags: cms, magento

Вывел похожие товары, но показывает все 20, которые я указал в админке. Как мне поставить ограничение, что бы показовалось, например, только 5 товаров, то есть автоматически выбирает из выбранных 5, а не 20

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение,кому то поможет. идем в `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` 
и ставим данный код в нужном месте

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php if($i++ == 5) break; ?>
```

при том,что `<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>` уже есть в `related.phtml`, соответсвенно просто добавляем `<?php $i = 0; ?>` и `<?php if($i++ == 5) break; ?>`, где 5 - это количество выводимого товара.

Comment: Плохое решение. 1. Вам нужно всего 5 item'ов а не все которые добавил человек, 2. Использование `foreach` вместо `for`. Можно создать модуль, его блок наследуете от класса этого блока, а после наследуем метод '_prepareCollection()' и в `collection->setPage(0)->setOffset(5)` ставим offset равный 5 и получаем такой же результат, но уже изначально с 5-ю elements.